# OST in the 2nd season of Magi episode 19 around 4:43

Tags: music, magi

I have been wondering what the song at 4:43 episode 19 is in *Magi* season 2, *Magi: The Kingdom of Magic*. It plays when

> the Leam and the Fanalis broke through the first barrier of Magnostadt and the Fanalis group leader did his little pep-talk to attack the mages of Magnostadt.

It sounds really nice but I cannot seem to find this one.

I've been going around some OST lists but can't seem to find this one specifically.

What is this OST called? Where could it be found?

Comment: Sometimes timestamp can be confusing, could you describe the scene on that timestamp shortly to make it clear?

Comment: @AkiTanaka did it but idk how to make the spoiler tag :S

Comment: To add a spoiler, start the paragraph with `>! `

Comment: @AkiTanaka Thx learned something here :D

Answer (score 1):

It is most definitely a mix of music but I definitely heard "Cast to Damnation" ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgldqHzyoik)) in there at around 7:20 .

Comment: Friendly advice, please don't use `>` (quotation block) to emphasize/add aesthetic because that's not the purpose. Quotation block should be used when you're quoting something, either from external site, posts on Stack Exchange, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, i see that is a mix but the problem was i really want to know what the music is at the start of that scene. still this one is also cool :D so thanks for the reaction at least :)